# Coloring excel cells based on percentiles

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm not sure if this is the correct forum for my question, but if it isn't, I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me where to direct it.  My question is specific to excel. I have a range of data which I would like to color according to percentile.

```
1385
5133
6001
4407
4846
5621
6018
8328
4904
8054
6401
7976
1326
8628
5690
8218
```

for example.

What I would like to do is color each cell based on its percentile ranking. I want to make the color scheme graduated; that is, the 99.999th percentile should be on the violet end of the color spectrum, while the .00001th percentile should be on the deep red end of the color spectrum.

I recognize that this may be a fairly complicated problem, but I assume it's a pretty common one.

Comment: Do you want 100.000 different variations on cells? Just a heads up, [Excel has a limit of unique cells styles](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3), 64.000 to be exact. Other than that, just go to Conditional Formatting and choose Color Scale.

Comment: Color scale only works with up to 3 colors. I would like a larger range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Excel's built in Conditional Formatting by selecting the range, clicking "Conditional Formatting" in the ribbon.  You will want to use a 3-color scale:

[image]

- Low end is red with RGB (255, 0, 0)
- 50% is green with RGB (0, 255, 0)
- High end is violet with RGB (159, 0, 255)

Comment: I did, but I realized that it bases it on the percentiles of entire sheet. I have a few columns that I would like to color code in this way based on their OWN percentiles. Is there a quick way to do that?

Comment: @AEStudent51345 You can apply conditional formatting to a specific range.  But you have to create those rules independently.